# React Native onTextLayout method of Text component issue on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-text

I use onTextLayout method in order to count the number of lines rendered. It works perfectly on Android, but on iOS the lines array length is 1 or 2, never bigger than two even if the text is very long.

Any ideas why?